# Visual Studio 2013 installation error: .NET 4.5 needs to be enabled, but already is

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. When I started the installation process, I got an error related to the .NET Framework 4.5.1, 0x800713ec Asia. I try to install .NET Framework 4.5.1 and I downloaded it from microsoft.com, but I have got the next issues:

> Blocking Issues:
>
> The .NET Framework 4.5 and this update are already installed on your
>   computer as part of the Windows operating system, but they must be
>   enabled. In Control Panel, choose Programs and Features, choose Turn
>   Windows features on or off, and then select the .NET Framework 4.5
>   check box.
>
> Setup cannot continue because a previous installation requires your
>   computer to be restarted. Please restart your computer and rerun
>   Setup.

I did this recommendation, but nothing happened.

Comment: Does 4.5 show up as enabled in Turn Windows features on or off? What error do you get after restarting and re-running setup?

Comment: Yes, .Net Framework 4.5 is enable in Turn Windows features on or off. When I restarting and reruning 4.5.1 setup I see the same issues:

Comment: Did you try restarting your computer after turning it on?

Comment: Yes. I restart computer after turning 3.5 on

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **settings** --> **power** --> and then **update and restart** . and then again **Run Setup**